# Is there any way I can get region name from WOEID (where on earth identifier)?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

For example: I have this WOEID, **2295424**, and I want to fetch the region name corresponding to this WOEID in Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [GET trends/available](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/trends/locations-with-trending-topics/api-reference/get-trends-available) endpoint with [`API.trends_available`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/api.html#API.trends_available) and iterate through each location to match the WOEID, e.g.:

```
>>> [location for location in api.trends_available() if location["woeid"] == 2295424]
[{'name': 'Chennai', 'placeType': {'code': 7, 'name': 'Town'}, 'url': 'http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2295424', 'parentid': 23424848, 'country': 'India', 'woeid': 2295424, 'countryCode': 'IN'}]
```

Another way is to use the [GET trends/place](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place) endpoint, which includes the name of the location in its response, with [`API.trends_place`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/api.html#API.trends_place), e.g.:

```
>>> api.trends_place(2295424)
[{'trends': [. . .], 'as_of': '2021-06-03T18:35:21Z', 'created_at': '2021-06-02T09:09:12Z', 'locations': [{'name': 'Chennai', 'woeid': 2295424}]}]
```